# Can I host WebRole and WorkerRole in same CloudService?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have a blank Solution in .Net and add two **Azure Cloud Services** project in solution. One with **WebRole** and other with **WorkerRole**. Can I host the both project in one cloudservice instance or need separate for both.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500803/deploy-a-web-role-and-worker-role-in-a-single-instance) SO question?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I just checked: That question is about combining functionality of roles, making one role behave as two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a single cloud service, you may certainly have multiple roles, a combination of web and worker roles, each with their own specific projects within your Visual Studio solution.

When you deploy, you'll have `yourapp.cloudapp.net` with all of your roles (at least one instance of each).

Your question is a bit unclear about what you're looking for, regarding solutions and project. But... All roles which must coexist within a `.cloudapp.net` deployment must all be within a single Visual Studio solution. You cannot combine roles from multiple Cloud Service solutions.

Comment: Thanks for response as you said we can not combine roles from multiple Cloud Services solutions but I have only one solution and within the solution I have two separate **azure cloud services** project one with webrole and another with worker role. For host the cloud service project we need to upload **package** and **serviceconfig** file on azure cloud service and I have different  **package** and **serviceconfig** for both project. So my question is that could we host the both on same instance or not?